LDAP v3 TLS Handshake failure with InsecureSkipVerify=true
My goal is to directly connect via LDAPS using the Go ldap v3 lib. The LDAP server does not support non-tls connections. The CLI-Tool "ldapsearch" can connect to the LDAP Server on the same machine (Intel Mac, Sequoia 15.1). Using the IP instead of URI results into the same error. Any idea is appreciated.
The error message is the following:
LDAP Result Code 200 "Network Error": remote error: tls: handshake failure

My Code:
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3"
)

func main() {
    username := os.Getenv("LUSERNAME")
    password := os.Getenv("LPASSWORD")

    ldapURL := "ldaps://ldap.example.com:636"

    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true, // Only for testing!
    }
    l, err := ldap.DialURL(ldapURL, ldap.DialWithTLSConfig(tlsConfig))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer l.Close()

    userdn := "uid=" + username + ",ou=people,dc=example,dc=de"

    err = l.Bind(userdn, password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}


[1/2] I would guess there may be differences in how the TLS connection is set up. Basically, there exist several versions of SSL (OK, SSL itself is deprecated but anyway) and 3 versions of TLS. Add to there that during the TLS handshake, the parties agee on a cipher suite (form the list they support) and so on. Hence, I would first get tcpdump/Wireshark and would capture the exchange ldapsearch does, and then would look closely to the connection setup (Wireshark has built-in dissector for TLS), and write down what version, cipher suites and other options get exchanged and agreed on. …

[2/2] I then would do the same when your program tries to set up a TLS connection and then study how what the program sends is different from what ldapsearch sends, and how the actual protocol error looks like. You could then try to guess at the reason. Note that even after gathering the data, you won't be able to make an educated guess. In that case, please do not post a question on SO but reach for other venues which allow multiple backs-and-forths for narroving down the problem https://go.dev/wiki/#the-go-community. The mailing list would be just fine.

«Note that even after gathering the data, you won't be able to make an educated guess» — sorry, of course, I meant to say, «it may so happen that even after gathering the data, you won't be able…».

remote error: tls: handshake failure This means the SERVER is rejecting the connection, so having InsecureSkipVerify on client TLS config wont change anything
Since in this case the server is rejecting the TLS handshake, most probably it would be expecting the client to provide some sort of certificate, try adding same in your TLS config. An example for same can be found in the tls package docs here
It is possible that the TLS version is not negotiated correctly between the client and server. In that case you can also add min version or accepted versions (and other configs) to your client's TLS config
